# SBT Command that Calls Another Command and an InputTask

Tags: scala, command, sbt

I am writing an SBT [`Command`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Commands.html) that is supposed to call another command (`eclipse` from the Eclipse SBT Plugin) and another [`InputTask`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Input-Tasks.html).

How can one achieve this?

Comment: Coverage of commands in the official SBT doc is pretty thin. Chapter 10 of _SBT in Action_, “Automating workflows with commands”, is a lot more informative.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to create a "release" command and it needs to call another task named "pack", you can add the following code to build.sbt:

```
commands += Command.command("release")((state:State) => {
  Project.evaluateTask(pack, state)
  println("release called")
  state
})
```

***Updated:***

In addition, if you have to create the "release" command and it requires calling another command named "init_compile", then the following sample code can be used:

```
commands += Command.command("init_compile")((state:State) => {
  println("init_compile called.")
  state
})

commands += Command.command("release")((state:State) => {
  val newState = Command.process("init_compile",state)
  println("release called.")
  newState
})
```

Comment: This does not pass the type checker. The `evaluateTask` accepts a `ScopedKey[Task[T]]` and I need to execute a `Command`.

Comment: I updated the answer and hopefully it should solve your problem. Calling a command from another command is simply done by calling [Command.process("command_name", state)](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/command/src/main/scala/sbt/Command.scala#L88).